# Inverse order of dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reverse

I have a python dictionary like the following:

```
myDict = {'cb_rdbu_4': [['202', '0', '32'], ['244', '165', '130'], ['146', '197', '222'], ['5', '113', '176']]}
```

I like to inverse the order of the elements in the list. So for instance for the first key value list I like to have the following order:

```
'cb_rdbu_4': [['5', '113', '176'], ['146', '197', '222'], ['244', '165', '130'], ['202', '0', '32']]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_dict = dict([(key,reversed(value)) for key,value in myDict.items()])
```

or if you want to edit it in place

```
for key in myDict:
    myDict[key] = reversed(myDict[key])
```

instead of `reversed(value)` you can do `value[::-1]`

Comment: This returns `<listreverseiterator object at 0x7fd4d0c36650>` as  values

Comment: oh not in python26 ... oh well easy fix

Comment: Actually in  python 2.7 and python 3 also. You need  list(reversed(value)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy one.

```
for key, val in myDict.items():
    myDict[key] = myDict[key][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to [`reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) all the [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) of the dictionary:

```
for seq in the_dict.values():
    seq.reverse()
```

If you are using python2 you may replace `values()` with [`itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) for better performance.

Note that this mutates the original dictionary. If you want to also preserve the original dictionary, you can create a new one with a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {key: list(reversed(value)) for key, value in original.items()}
```

Or:

```
new_dict = {key: value[::-1] for key, value in original.items()}
```

If you are using an older version of python that doesn't provide dictionary comprehension you can use:

```
new_dict = dict((key, list(reversed(value))) for key, value in original.items())
```